# How to create a dynamic table by iterating array vales in to <tr> and store in variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, node.js

I have an array object.I need to create  a table where tablerow (tr) should be dynamic and the tr values should be from array object.Then I need to store that in a variable.So that  I can pass that to restcall so that it triggers an email and that table is displayed in my email.

```
mail is my array with values{"100","200","300","400"}...
for ( i=0;i<=mail.length;i++){
var bodytext = "<html><table><tr><th>Request</th></tr><‌​tr>" + mail[i]+"</tr></table></html>";

}
window.postMsg({body:bodytext,subject:"DATA"}, "*");
```

I tried this.But the above is giving result as

```
   Request
<tr>undefined
```

But I  need result in my mail something like

```
Request
 100
 200
 300
 400
```

How can we do this.Any help appreciated!

Comment: You said array but your syntax looks like object? Is it an object?

Comment: Try to console log mail and post here

Comment: @MehulMohan ["5007348100-012017-02-24 09:16:14.885", "500 2017-02-24 09:10:36.608", "500 2017-02-23 16:16:53.260", ]

Comment: Doesn't look like ["100","200",...] as you said

Answer (score 0):

This is a job for string concatenation and the [`Array#join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) method.

```
var body = '<html><table><tr><th>Request</th></tr><tr><td>'
  + mail.join('</td></tr><tr><td>') + '</td></tr></table></html>'

window.postMsg({ body: body, subject: 'DATA' }, '*')
```

### Demo

```js
var mail = [100, 200, 300, 400]

var body = '<html><table><tr><th>Request</th></tr><tr><td>'
  + mail.join('</td></tr><tr><td>') + '</td></tr></table></html>'

document.body.innerHTML = body.slice(6, -7)

// uncomment when you want to use
// window.postMsg({ body: body, subject: 'DATA' }, '*')
```

Comment: It worked but It doesnt looks like table..How can we we add style tag here to add cell padding and cell spacing to that html

Comment: What do you see? Is it just plain text (like you see all the `<html>...</html> stuff) or is there some other styling problem?

Comment: No..I mean it is working just as your demo..But I want to add cell padding and cellspacing to table..How can we do that?

Comment: [This article from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Styling_boxes/Styling_tables) should point you in the right direction.

Answer (score -1):

Try it hope it will work

```
var mail = {"100","200","300","400"};
var bodytext  = "<html>";
   bodytext +=     "<body>";
   bodytext +=     "<table>";
   bodytext +=       "<tr>";
   bodytext +=         "<th>Request</th>";
   bodytext +=       "</tr>";

   $(mail).each(function(index,element){
      bodytext +=       "<tr>";
      bodytext +=         "<td>" + element +  "</td>";
      bodytext +=       "</tr>";
   });

   bodytext +=    "</table>";
   bodytext +=     "<body>";
   bodytext  += "<html>";
```

window.postMsg({body:bodytext,subject:"DATA"}, "*");

Comment: Do you realize that `var mail = {"100","200","300","400"};` is just plain wrong?

Comment: You can replace it by an array and it will work as the same